# design a button with a custom image? is it possible?

Tags: asp.net, .net, user-interface, web-parts

Is it possible to put a button on my user control `.ascx` (the web part in this case), and have a customized image with that? What I am trying to do is have a "print" button to print the page.

However, I don't want to use the default asp button, I want to have a the special "print" icon associated with it. So, can I do this and still use `<asp:button>`?

Or is it just better to make that "print" icon a link, and do `OnClick` on the link event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use link button as suggested.
But in my opinion you should not use any server-side control if you don't have to use it on server side.
What you can do create an image tag `<img src....` and use `onclick` event on this image.

When you create a server side controls it is added to your `view state` `key value` pair of information. Which is an overhead.

or you can use like this

```
<a href="javascript:window.print()">
     <img src="print.gif">
</a>
```

or even

```
<img src="print.gif" name="pic" onclick="javascript:window.print()"/>
```

Comment: Good point about not using a server-control when it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [ImageButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx) class, then you can have a printer icon for example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="submitButton" runat="server" OnClick="submitButton_Click" ImageUrl="~/images/printer.jpg" />
```

Comment: Hi:
I tried the ImageButton option
<div>
<span id="sharethis_twitter" class='st_twitter_large'></span>
 <span id="sharethis_email" class='st_email_large'></span>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="submitButton" runat="server" OnClick="submitButton_Click" ImageUrl=""/>
</div>
 But for some reason, I am getting a 404 error on that page. This is just an .ascx file
 
 which is really weird, do I need to add <asp:panel> to the web part? Please let me know.
 
 Thanks